# Kotlin Hashmap: Change key value and subelement value

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I am new to Kotlin (and Java) and had a question: I have a Hashmap called `data`. I would like to change the key values (e.g. `"Training Day 1"` to `"Blablabla"`) and also the values within the ArrayList (e.g. at `trainingDay2` change `"Player8"` to `"Player1"`). Furthermore I would like to add elements to `trainingDay4`. How would I do that?

```
val data: HashMap<String, List<String>> get() {
    val listData = HashMap<String, List<String>>()

    val trainingDay1 = ArrayList<String>()
    trainingDay1.add("Player1")
    trainingDay1.add("Player2")
    trainingDay1.add("Player3")
    trainingDay1.add("Player4")
    trainingDay1.add("Player5")
    trainingDay1.add("Player6")
    trainingDay1.add("Player7")

    val trainingDay2 = ArrayList<String>()
    trainingDay2.add("Player8")
    trainingDay2.add("Player9")
    trainingDay2.add("Player10")
    trainingDay2.add("Player11")
    trainingDay2.add("Player12")

    val trainingDay3 = ArrayList<String>()
    trainingDay3.add("Player13")
    trainingDay3.add("Player14")
    trainingDay3.add("Player15")
    trainingDay3.add("Player16")
    trainingDay3.add("Player17")
    trainingDay3.add("Player18")

    val trainingDay4 = ArrayList<String>()

    listData["Training Day 1"] = trainingDay1
    listData["Training Day 2"] = trainingDay2
    listData["Training Day 3"] = trainingDay3
    listData["Training Day 4"] = trainingDay4

    return listData
}
```

I tried using replace and put methods, but they won't do the thing.

```
data.replace("Training Day 1", listOf("Training Day 4"))
data.keys
res45: kotlin.collections.MutableSet<kotlin.String> = [Training Day 1, Training Day 2, Training Day 3, "Training Day 4"]

data.put("Training Day 1", listOf("Player000"))
res40: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.String>? = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4", "Player5", "Player6", "Player7"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to change the key values (e.g. "Training Day 1" to
> "Blablabla")

```
data.remove("Training Day 1")?.let {
  data.put("Blablabla", it)
}
```

> and also the values within the ArrayList (e.g. at trainingDay2 change
> "Player8" to "Player1").

```
data["Training Day 2"] = data.getValue("Training Day 2").map { 
  if (it == "Player8") "Player1" else it 
}
```

> Furthermore I would like to add elements to trainingDay4

```
data["Training Day 4"] = data.getValue("Training Day 4") + "Player19"
```

Given that you need to mutate the list often, I would suggest to change the type of `data` to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. Then you can perform last two operations as

```
//replace
data["Training Day 2"]?.let { 
  it[it.indexOf("Player8")] = "Player1"
}

// add
data["Training Day 4"]?.add("Player19")
```

Comment: Any reason for usage of the getValue() method `data["Training Day 4"] = data.getValue("Training Day 4") + "Player19"` instead of simply `data["Training Day 4"] = data["Training Day 4"] + "Player19"`?

Comment: `get` returns a nullable value. `getValue` throws exception if the key not found. Just simplified the answer by using `getValue` otherwise I had to handle null check, or use unsafe !!